# Does SQL Server need extensions to do spatial?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does SQL Server need extensions to do spatial like Oracle does?
Just wondering if there will be extra costs for implementing a SQL Server backend to SDE.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you asking about?

Answer (score 5):

@pecoanddeco is correct.  As of SQL Server 2008, the spatial capabilities are built in.  They even come with the express editions.

Just to be 100% clear, though, the spatial capabilities are not completely necessary for ArcSDE.  ArcSDE uses its own spatial format by default, which means that you do not need a spatially enabled database in the backend.  However, if you have a spatially enabled database in the backend, you have much more flexibility to use the database native spatial types instead of the SDE Binary spatial type.

Comment: With 2008 the [Sql Server Spatial Tools on Codeplex](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/)  are very helpful, some might argue they are essential.  You can use them with [query layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_query_layer/00s500000027000000/) without involving ArcSDE.  I've heard these tools have been rolled into the core product for Sql Server 2012, but have not confirmed this.

Comment: I've used those tools.  They are very helpful.  I forgot about query layers.  Although, those are still very new to ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

All the SQL Server spatial stuff comes as part of the standard license so there's no extra cost, so it's a bit different to the Oracle Locator/Spatial split.

There a bit more detail [here](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008r2_oracle11gr2_postgis15_compare) (though it's a bit buried):